# Firebase Notifications: Issue with Browsers

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firebase, firefox, push-notification

I have an Angular 5 and Firebase 4.10 app which listens to changes in a Firebase database and triggers Notifications accordingly. Whenever a new notifications is created in Firebase, as `{ "body": "some body", "title": "some title" }`, the `onCreate` function in `index.js` below will send to the user's device his FCM token and the appropriate payload:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.fcmSend = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  const message = snapshot.val();
  const userId  = 'user';

  const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: message.title,
          body: message.body,
          icon: 'favicon.ico'
        }
      };

   admin.database()
        .ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`)
        .once('value')
        .then(token => token.val() )
        .then(userFcmToken => {
          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcmToken, payload)
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Sent Successfully", res);
          return 'Success!';
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Below is the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase-messaging.js")

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    databaseURL: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

And below is the Angular 5 Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/messaging';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  messaging = firebase.messaging();
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  private updateToken(token) {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return;
      } else {
        const data = { [ user.uid ]: token };
        this.db.object('fcmTokens/').update(data);
      }
    });
  }

  getPermission () {
    this.messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
      return this.messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(token => {
      this.updateToken(token);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify!', error);
    });
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      console.log(payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
  }

}
```

I have the following issues:

1. The above system works in sending Notifications to the user in Firefox, but only when the app is not the current tab or closed (browser is open in desktop). If the app is the current tab, I can see from the console that the payload was sent but no notification is fired.
2. No notifications ever arrive in Chrome, regardless of whether the app is open or closed. There are no errors or warnings in the console.